# Fatal error when value empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fatal error claiming that I have a string when I thought I had an array :

`Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tankards_wordpress/wp-content/themes/tankardsleague/functions.php on line 566`

and also the following warning :
`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tankards_wordpress/wp-content/themes/tankardsleague/functions.php on line 579`

I am guessing that I have either a syntax problem somewhere? I thought I had initailized the variables but maybe I missed one? I would appreciate some more experienced eyes having a look.

```
function forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    global $user_ID;
    $players= get_users();

    foreach($players as $player)
    {
        $user_info = get_userdata($player->ID);
        $playeremail = $user_info->user_email;

        if(!empty($playeremail) && user_can( $player-> ID, 'contributor'))
        {                   
            $list = get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', array());


            if( is_player_subscribed($player->ID)) //remove player if already exists (user clicked unsubscribe)
            {
                $key = array_search($playeremail, $list);
                unset($list[$key]);
            }
            else
                $list[] = $playeremail;
            update_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', $list);
        }
    }       
}

function is_player_subscribed($user_ID)
{
    if($user_ID)
      {
        $useremail = get_userdata($user_ID, 'user_email');

        $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", array());
        if(!empty($list) && in_array($useremail, $list))
        {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }

}

function call_forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    forum_subscribe_member_player();
}
```

line 566 is `$list[] = $playeremail;` line 579 is `if(!empty($list) && in_array($useremail, $list))`

Comment: well you can type-cast the `$list` to an array to make sure it's always an array: `$list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', array());`

Comment: line 566 is `$list[] = $playeremail;` line 579 is `      if(!empty($list) && in_array($useremail, $list))`

Comment: Thanks @Twisted1919 that takes care of the warning but still gettig the fatal error for `$list[] = $playeremail;` $playeremail is indeed a string but I'm trying to add an array of them.

Comment: @Twisted1919 got it thanks (I didn't use your suggestion for both instances) If you want to put it in answer form that was indeed the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can type-cast the `$list` to an array to make sure it's always an array even if the initial value is null/empty/etc (basically any type except array):

```
$list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', array());
```